# Is food safe to eat with grey or black residue on it?

Tags: cookware

I noticed that every time I leave my food over night in my stainless steel caserole dish, there is this grey/black residue on it.

I ate some of the food but after I saw this residue, I got scared the food is poisoned.

*It it?*

Comment: Welcome to [cooking.se]!  **:-)**  Without chemical analysis it's rather difficult to ascertain whether the food has been poisoned (or not) and without a picture *totally impossible.*  Please [edit] your question and provide more tangible data.

Comment: It would also really help to know some detail about both the cooking vessel and the food.

Comment: I wonder if the stainless is really stainless. That sounds like some electrochemistry is going on: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrochemistry

Answer (score 3):

Most likely the casserole dish is not stainless steel.  If only because stainless steel is designed specifically not to chemically interact with the food, and will never discolor it.

That said, if it was my dish I'd get rid of it, or at least never let food sit in it longer than strictly necessary for cooking.  Who know what you're ingesting, and most metals are toxic.

Comment: There are lots of different platings that can make pot metal look like stainless.  You find out it's not as advertised when you try to put concentrated sulfuric acid in them.

Comment: No need to handle dangerous chemicals when the performance with food is already inadequate

Comment: I like real stainless for food, but also use it for other stuff. Real or not matters in both cases. If a vessel discolors either when cooking or cleaning up rocks, I'll toss it.